# Jquery bind transitions to css

Tags: javascript, css, append, transition

Note: The examples are tested with chrome. 
Firefox ia not working.

I have this js code to append css transitions.

For a single image (working):

```
    var isTransition = false;
var isRemoveQueue = false;

$( ".text" ).bind( "webkitTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd transitionEnd", function () {
    isTransition = false;
    if ( isRemoveQueue ) {
        $( this ).removeClass("animated-hover");
    }
});

$(".text").on( 'mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).addClass("animated-hover");
    isTransition = true;
    isRemoveQueue = false;
});

$(".text").on( 'mouseleave', function () {
    if ( !isTransition ) {
        $( this ).removeClass( "animated-hover" );
    } else {
        isRemoveQueue = true;
    }
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/drecodeam/3pb38v4f/6/

It was important to me, that the transition does not stop if you just hover quick over the image. It is working good with one image.

Here is the thing: If i am using more images than one, i have weird effects, like the transition getting stuck e.g.

Example with more images:

https://jsfiddle.net/3pb38v4f/9/

Beside it is not working correctly, it is also not working with **firefox**.

Comment: maybe on the last function, on mouseleave, try if ( isTransition != false); also those 2 js fiddle links are both the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoverflow is exactly what i was looking for.

It can handle the queuing in js very nice and clean :)

http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

```
$(".text").on( 'mouseleave', function () {
    $( this ).removeClass( "animated-hover" );
    isRemoveQueue = true;
});
```

I think you over thought it a little :)

Comment: I didnt, because the transition of each image should be fully executed even if i just hover quick over the images from left to right e.g. You can see what i mean in the second fiddle.